# to_sql raising vague KeyError: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

```
id,1,2,1ah,2ah,ah_line
13399,1.08,10.03,2.0,1.89,-13.5
13400,1.07,11.25,2.0,1.89,-19.5
13401,1.22,4.84,1.97,1.93,-9.0
13402,3.09,1.43,1.99,1.92,5.0
```

I am trying to populate mysql database via pandas `DataFrame.to_sql` method and for some loose reason it is raising `KeyError: <class 'numpy.float64'>`.

```
print(df.dtypes)
id           int64
1          float64
2          float64
1ah        float64
2ah        float64
ah_line    float64
dtype: object
```

I am drawing a blank, any ideas? I've done it quite a few times and never got this error.

**Edit**

Oddly enough it works well with basically same data, e.g.:

```
id,q1,q2,q3,q4,ot1,ot2
13399,16.0,17.0,17.0,19.0,na,na
13400,20.0,17.0,20.0,16.0,na,na
13401,18.0,19.0,17.0,18.0,na,na
13402,15.0,17.0,17.0,16.0,na,na
```

info:

```
pandas==0.13.1
cymysql==0.7.2
```

Full Tracebback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bartek/Desktop/buckypy3/plk-working.py", line 389, in <module>
    df.to_sql('plk_odds', con=conn, flavor='mysql', if_exists='append')
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1261, in to_sql
    self, name, con, flavor=flavor, if_exists=if_exists, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 238, in write_frame
    func(frame, name, safe_names, cur)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 264, in _write_mysql
    cur.executemany(insert_query, data)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cymysql/cursors.py", line 144, in executemany
    self.execute(query, params)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cymysql/cursors.py", line 118, in execute
    escaped_args = tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cymysql/cursors.py", line 118, in <genexpr>
    escaped_args = tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cymysql/connections.py", line 294, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset, self.encoders)
  File "/home/bartek/py3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cymysql/converters.py", line 354, in escape_item
    encoder = encoders[type(val)]
KeyError: <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: What's the full traceback? Line number/file of where the KeyError occurs will likely show most of the answer.

Comment: Can you give some more information: pandas version, mysql driver (pymysql, MySQLdb, ..?) and version of that.

Comment: Could you try if you also have this issue with `pymysql`? (if this is possible, `cymysql` is not tested for). Another guess to try: in the first df you have some integer column names, can you try to rename then (but I don't think this will be the cause)? If possible, it would also be interesting if you could try this out with pandas 0.14 (release candidate out previous week: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases).

Comment: It seems `pymysql` has the same issue, but I tested in with 0.14 and there the issue seems already solved (there was a big refactor of the sql module in 0.14). Final 0.14 will be released this weekend.

Comment: Thank you for your help joris! I will wait for the 0.14. Please consider submitting new post solution so that I can upvote and mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bug in pandas 0.13.1 (I can reproduce it with both `cymysql` as `pymysql`), but I am not sure about the reason of the bug.

I tested it with pandas 0.14 and there the issue seems already solved (at least with `pymysql`). There was was a big refactor of the sql module in 0.14 (see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0140-sql)), to  now use sqlalchemy to support different database flavors. Final 0.14 will be released May 31, 2014.